# Pagination Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I got this script from internet and it's actually one of the best I have found but there's a slight problem and I can't get why and can't fix it so I hope you can give me a hand. Here's the code:

Function:

```
<?php

/**
 * @link: http://www.Awcore.com/dev
 */

   function pagination($query, $per_page = 10,$page = 1, $url = '?'){        
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM {$query}";
        $row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
        $total = $row['num'];
        $adjacents = "2"; 

        $page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page);  
        $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;                               

        $prev = $page - 1;                          
        $next = $page + 1;
        $lastpage = ceil($total/$per_page);
        $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;

        $pagination = "";
        if($lastpage > 1)
        {   
            $pagination .= "<ul class='pagination'>";
                    $pagination .= "<li class='details'>Page $page of $lastpage</li>";
            if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))
            {   
                for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                }
            }
            elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
                {
                    for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                    }
                    $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>";      
                }
                elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
                {
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
                    for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                    }
                    $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>";      
                }
                else
                {
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
                    for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($page < $counter - 1){ 
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$next'>Next</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>Last</a></li>";
            }else{
                $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Next</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Last</a></li>";
            }
            $pagination.= "</ul>\n";        
        }


        return $pagination;
    } 
?>
```

Page code:

```
//get the function
include_once ('function.php');

$page = (int) (!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
$limit = 1;
$startpoint = ($page * $limit) - $limit;

//to make pagination

$colname_statement = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['id_game'])) {
$colname_statement = $_GET['id_game'];
}
$statement = sprintf("tournaments, games WHERE tournaments.id_game = %s AND tournaments.id_game = games.id_game ORDER BY id_tournament DESC", GetSQLValueString($colname_statement, "int"));
```

I'll explain the problem now.

Explanation: On the index is other page I have this code and its working fine.

Well on the index page this pagination works fine, show two records and when I click next it shows the other two records and the urls goes from index.php to `index.php?page=2` so actually its working fine.

Explanation: This page is the one I want to fix it the page itself has the name: page.php and it only shows the records based on id that gets from index.php, example: `page.php?id=1, page.php?id=2`...

But now on this page the records is supossed to show only the data from id=1/2/3
so when i go to page.php?id=1 and click on next the page that goes to is `page.php?page=2` and its wrong what should go its `page.php?id=1&page=2` the correct href, anyways if I type this on the url bar it actually works but the buttons next and last its not going to the proper url.

Some Help please, can't figured out the problem.

Comment: Your question is not clear specially paragraph starting with "But now on this page".

Comment: i add some explanation

Comment: Do you meant say that you have 2 pages namely index.php and page.php and pagination is working fine in index.php and not in page.php ?

Comment: yes, cause index.php is a single page and page.php have id attribute like page.php?id=(number) and when i use that pagination the page change the url to page.php?page=(number) and its wrong, the correct format should be page.php?id=(number)&page=(number), but dont know how to change it.

Comment: Assuming ``pagination()`` function generates pagination for both pages, Where this function getting called in page.php?  Whatever code you shared for page.php, is it complete code ??